# Refactoring the namespace of a class with a DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    [DataContract]
    public Data
    {
          [DataMember] public int Value1 {get;set;}
          [DataMember] public double Value2 {get;set;}
          [DataMember] public MyClass Value3 {get;set;}
    }
}

namespace X.Y.Z
{
    [DataContract]
    public Dataset
    {
        [DataMember] public Data Data1 {get;set;}
        [DataMember] public int Data2 {get;set;}
        // ...
    }
}
```

I haven been serializing and deserializing `Dataset` objects with the default `DataContractSerializer`. Now, during refactoring I changed the namespace of `Data` from `A.B.C` to `A.B.C.D` and deserialization no longer works: The DataMembers of `Data` are all 0.

I tried to fix this by adding the old namespace to the DataContract:

```
namespace A.B.C.D
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "A.B.C")]
    public Data
    {
          [DataMember] public int Value1 {get;set;}
          [DataMember] public double Value2 {get;set;}
          [DataMember] public MyClass Value3 {get;set;}
    }
}
```

But that does not fix it. I also tried a clean rebuild and redeploy (Windows Store App), just in case, but still nothing.

How do I fix the deserialization?

Comment: @gleng What proxy files?

Comment: @gleng There is no service client, just an app storing local data as files via data contract serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the namespace is not specified explicitly, it is prefixed. What you do need is to decorate the class with something like:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/A.B.C")]
```